# Finding the Perfect Keyboard

Tags: piano, keyboard

I accompany high school and middle school choirs, and do rehearsal piano and pit keyboards for school musicals.  I often have to haul my own gear around, and I have been on a multi-year quest to find the right keyboard.

I do not want a rhythm section.  I do not need automatic accompaniment.  I do not need sampling, and I don't need the ability to create new types of sound.  What I DO want is the ability to set up a list of "favorite" patches, and the ability to recall a favorite with a simple button press, in a keyboard that won't break my back while I haul it in.

I had a Casio PX-5S.  It had favorites list, but they weren't easy to get to.  I currently have a Casio PX-S3000 (30 pounds).  It's actually pretty close, but the rhythm section is front and center, and because it's touch sensitive, it's way too easy to trigger it accidentally.

I'd appreciate any advice on where to look.  Since this is asking for recommendations, this may be deemed off-topic.  I'll understand that.

Comment: Sorry, vtc as it's about recommendations. Recently, the conductor of a big band I work with told me to go find a k'bd as I always humped my own to rehearsals and gigs. A tour of local shops (few) resulted in a k'bd as good as mine (but heavier!) that's now all set up for rehearsals - although I have a feeling I'll still turn up for gigs with my own gear. Moral - go out looking. You may not even find anything to top your own...

Comment: Please consider posting in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Comment: Perhaps this question could be made on-topic by revising to ask *HOW* you might overcome the limitations of the interface on your PX-S3000.  What *kind* of gear and what configuration would make it easier to recall favorites when the front panel is less-than-ideal.